# Asp.net mvc 3 load razor views from a physical path

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I am tring to load razor views from a physical path that is outside of my webapp.
Is it that possible for you?

Thanks

Marco

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a custom virtual path provider. Here's a [nice article](http://rebuildall.umbraworks.net/2009/11/17/ASP_NET_MVC_and_virtual_views) illustrating how to achieve this (it loads views stored in a database but it could be easily adapted to load them from any physical location).